# Azure Pipeline repo name condition skipped

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm creating a pipeline that uses 2 repositories. In the `Build_Dev` stage, I only want to run it if it's from the repo `Test`. However, every time the pipeline runs, the `Build_Dev` stage is always skipped (although the commit is from `Test` repo). Below is the yaml. What did I do wrong with the `condition` in `Build_Dev` stage? The Info stage recognizes`$(Build.Repository.Name)` as `Test` (which is correct).

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: PipelineRepo
    type: git
    name: 'Test/pipeline-config'
  - repository: App
    type: git
    name: 'Test/Test'
    trigger:
    - Dev
    - Test*

stages:
- stage: Info
  displayName: Info
  jobs:
  - job: 'Info'
    displayName: 'Print Info: Repo: $(Build.Repository.Name) / Branch: $(Build.SourceBranch)'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
    steps:
    - script: 'echo "Repo: $(Build.Repository.Name) / Branch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"'
      displayName: 'Write build info'

- stage: 'Build_Dev'
  dependsOn: Info
  displayName: 'Build the web application in Dev'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Test')
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

    variables:
      dotnetSdkVersion: '5.x'

    steps:
    - checkout: App
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET SDK $(dotnetSdkVersion)'
      inputs:
        version: '$(dotnetSdkVersion)'

    - script: 'echo "$(Build.DefinitionName), $(Build.BuildId), $(Build.BuildNumber), repo: $(Build.Repository.Name), branch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"'
      displayName: 'Write build info'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build the project - Dev'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        arguments: '--no-restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Publish the project - Dev'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        publishWebProjects: false
        arguments: '--no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Dev'
        zipAfterPublish: true

    - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: drop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

[image]

You can use below method to get let the condition get the right value:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=reponame;isOutput=true]$(build.repository.name)"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  condition: eq(dependencies.A.outputs['A1.printvar.reponame'], 'YourRepoName')
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Stage B
```

Above yaml file works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: This might be the solution I'm looking for! Thank you! I didn't think of assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), I think this is the reason:

[image]

Comment: I saw that, but I didn't know how to get around that. In addition, I saw sample code that specifies the same variable in the condition.